# Trouble installing ROS kinetic on Debian Stretch

Tags: unix, debian, ros, debian-stretch

I'm new to this forum, as well as I am new to ROS and Debian. I am trying to install ROS on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ which runs Debian Stretch. I'm currently following the tutorial linked below:

https://neverbenever.wordpress.com/2017/12/20/install-ros-and-opencv-in-raspberry-piraspbian-stretch/

I'm having trouble at the step "**Build ROS:**", where I have to run:

pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated -j2 --install --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

This works for other packages up and until that of "roscpp", which gives me a result like this:

```
<== Finished processing package [44 of 52]: 'xmlrpcpp'

==> Processing catkin package: 'roscpp'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/roscpp'
make: *** No rule to make target 'cmake_check_build_system'.  Stop.
<== Failed to process package 'roscpp': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh', 'make', 'cmake_check_build_system']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/roscpp && /opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh make cmake_check_build_system

Command failed, exiting.

I've been cracking my head at this for a long time. I'm also new to UNIX and just want to get ROS up and running between my Raspberry Pi 3+ and Arduino for my robot. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [See this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi). Though this is not for Debian Stretch, it is the official guide, but you can see that all dependencies are not installed beforehand. So, maybe try to install those dependencies and then build again.

Comment: Thank you Akshay, I'll try out what you have suggested. Will update on any results here.